# Visual studio 2019 gives me error "Root element is missing"

Tags: c#, xaml

I get the error "Root element is missing" but don't know why. I'm very new to xaml and c# and have to add some stuff for a testing program for work. Everything started of well and none of these errors occurred before. All of a sudden I get this error on code that I haven't even touched before. I also get the Error  "Cannot find resource named 'Locator'. Resource names are case sensitive" in a different class but I think it is because of the first error. The first error comes from this code:

```
<Application x:Class="InductorSolderMeasurementSystem.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             d1p1:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
  
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:InductorSolderMeasurementSystem.ViewModel"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I honestly have no idea why this error occurs all of a sudden. I'm not sure of how much more code I can give since it's a bit company confidential...
but hopefully this is enough to give some clarity.

Comment: Please read the page on creating a [mcve]. It's a great technique that assists you in debugging and also, if it doesn't become obvious what the issue is to you, gives us a chance to *see the problem for real on our own machines*. Whereas now you're showing us code that you *suspect* is relevant but have no real means of knowing that for sure.

Comment: (And by re-creating it as a fresh new project, you can avoid inserting any company confidential aspects into it at all, thus alleviating that concern)

Comment: In the App.xaml file you posted, you set up that you use "MainWindow.xaml" as the main window of the application (line 4). You should post the code of that file too.

Comment: The code needs to be recompiled using Clean Build.  Probably the to main window "clr-namespace:InductorSolderMeasurementSystem.ViewModel" is not being found.

Comment: I found out that it was something else not related to this that was the problem giving a different error message. I still have have the "root" error but the program seems to be running without problem at the moment. Right now I won't check on that problem but I will try to solve it some time later and will probably ask more here then and add more of the code for clarity. Thank you for trying to help so far!